# OPC Publisher - Filter values from node when publishing

Tags: azure-iot-hub, opc-ua, azure-iot-edge

I have recently set up a IoT Edge up in one of our machines and installed OPC Publisher and connected it to one of our opc-ua servers. I got it publishing the nodes correctly and routing them to the iot hub, so that's awesome. Though I have now run into the following problem:

This is how our node structure looks like atm. (anonymized):

[image: Node Structure]

And we asked OPC Publisher to publish the OPC-UA_COMM.OUT Node. The Publish node config looks something like this:

```json
[
    {
        "EndpointUrl": "{opcuaConnectionString}",
        ...
        "OpcNodes": [
            {
                "Id": "ns=3;s=\"OPC-UA_COMM\".\"OUT\"",
                "DisplayName": "OUT Message",
                "SkipFirst": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Problem is though, the temperature value is incredibly noisy and not relevant at the moment. I would like to be able to filter it away, so that I don't get a node published every time that value changes.

I have [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-accelerators/howto-opc-publisher-configure), and it seems like it is possible to configure content of the json message that is sent. It seems like it is possible to filter away specific values, although I have not succeeded in that yet. I created the following config file:

```json
{
    "Defaults": {
        "EndpointUrl": {
            "Publish": true,
            "Pattern": "(.*)",
            "Name": "EndpointUrl"
        },
        "NodeId": {
            "Publish": true,
            "Name": "NodeId"
        },
        "MonitoredItem": {
            "Flat": true,
            "ApplicationUri": {
                "Publish": true,
                "Name": "ApplicationUri"
            },
            "DisplayName": {
                "Publish": true,
                "Name": "DisplayName"
            }
        },
        "Value": {              
            "SourceTimestamp": {
                "Publish": true,
                "Name": "SourceTimestamp"
            },
            "StatusCode": {
                "Publish": false,
                "Name": "StatusCode"
            },
            "Status": {
                "Publish": false,
                "Name": "Status"
            },
            "Value:": {  
                "Temperature": {
                    "Publish": false,
                    "Name": "Temperature"
                },
                "DoorsOpen": {
                    "Publish": true,
                    "Name": "DoorsOpen"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added it to the container, verified the file was there, and made sure that the publisher module was started with the correct settings. This is how the container create options look like:

```json
{
 "Hostname": "publisher",
 "Cmd": [
   "OPCPublisher",
   "--tc=/appdata/nodeConfiguration.json",
   "--pf=/appdata/opcPublisher.json",
   "--tp=/appdata/pki/trusted",
   "--rp=/appdata/pki/rejected",
   "--ap=/appdata/pki/own",
   "--ip=/appdata/pki/issuer",
   "--aa",
   "--to",
   "--di=600"
 ],
 "HostConfig": {
   "Binds": [
     "/etc/iotedge/storage/publisher:/appdata"
   ]
 }
}
```

But still, it is being published! I would really appreciate some help.

I also understand that I could break it up into multiple different publishes. I have tried something like this:

```json
[
    {
        "EndpointUrl": "{opcuaConnectionString}",
        ...
        "OpcNodes": [
            {
                "Id": "ns=3;s=\"OPC-UA_COMM\".\"OUT\".\"DoorsOpen\"",
                "DisplayName": "Doors open",
                "SkipFirst": false
            },
            {
                "Id": "ns=3;s=\"OPC-UA_COMM\".\"OUT\".\"Speed\"",
                "DisplayName": "Speed",
                "SkipFirst": false
            },
            {
                "Id": "ns=3;s=\"OPC-UA_COMM\".\"OUT\".\"Weight\"",
                "DisplayName": "Weight",
                "SkipFirst": false
            }
            ...
        ]
    }
]
```

And it works! I can control which sub values arrive. But they each come separately, and I would much rather have it all come together in one node.

Comment: Are you leveraging this github repo for your implementation, see : https://github.com/azure/iot-edge-opc-publisher#configuring-opc-publisher

Comment: Yes I have! I mention that exact page in my question, but was not capable of achieving what I was trying to do.

Comment: As you can notice in he top of the doc (marked as important), the most updated info is here: https://azure.github.io/Industrial-IoT/ . I would recommend you follow steps from the github repos and not from docs while it is being updated.